# Density function of a coordinate of a randomly taken point from a sphere

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A point $A(X,Y,Z)$ is taken randomly from a sphere with center $\mathbf{0}=(0,0,0)$ and radius $R=1$. Determine the density of $X$ and the probability $\mathbb{P}(\text{min}(\vert X \vert, \vert Y\vert,\vert Z\vert)<0,9)$.

What I thought of is: fix $x \in (-1,1)$. Then
$$\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=1-\mathbb{P}(X>x)=1-\frac{S_{\text{spherical cap}}}{S_{\text{whole sphere}}}=1-\frac{2 \pi (1-x)}{4 \pi}=1-\frac{1-x}{2}=\frac{1+x}{2}$$

from where $f_X(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\frac{1}{2}$.
However my intuition tells me that this is wrong, hence I haven't determined the probability (my assumption is that they would be identically distributed, but have no idea whatsoever how to tackle it). Thank you in advance.

Comment: The result and the reasoning look good to me. Also note that $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 1$, which implies that $|X|, |Y|$ and $|Z|$ cannot be simultaneously larger than $0.9$. It means that it is certain that one of them is smaller than $0.9$.

Comment: your computation is correct, you have that $f_X=\frac1{2}\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$

Answer (score 1):

If you want a distribution assuming all points om surface have equal probability, use spherical coordinates.  Differential (unit radius) is $d\phi sin\theta d\theta$, where $\phi$ is longitude and $\theta$ is latitude.  $X=sin\theta cos\phi$, etc.